# Which form is はじめまして?

Tags: verbs, conjugations, greetings

So I've learned that はじめまして is used in first meetings and that it stems from the verb はじめる (to start; to begin). But what form is it? It's apparently not the polite past form, which has a -た at the end (はじめました). Is it a proper verb form of はじめる anyway or should it simply be seen as a set expression?

Comment: A post about this form I wrote sometime back: http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/20/whats-with-the-japanese-〜まして-form-mashite/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To break it down, はじめまして is the て form of はじめます, and はじめます is the polite form of はじめる.

はじめまして is a fixed expression.

You'll see ～～まして in some fixed expressions such as:

> - あけ**まして**おめでとうございます。-- Happy new year.
> - どういたし**まして**。-- You are welcome.

as well as in polite/formal speech or writing such as:

> - ご来店ください**まして**、誠にありがとうございます。
>     -- Thank you for visiting our store.
> - ご迷惑をおかけし**まして**、申し訳ございません。
>     -- We are sorry to have troubled you.

Comment: Can I ask a question? It seems the verb 初(はじ)める isn't found.

Comment: 明鏡国語辞典 gives 始 for the verb はじめる, and gives 初 for はじめて and はじめまして, adding 「もと『始』も使ったが、今はもっぱら『初』。」, which indicates that はじめて and はじめまして are derived from the verb はじめる (or, at least these three share the same origin).

Comment: Thank you for teaching. I first think only 初めまして is correct but it seems 始めまして is also correct. http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~QM4H-IIM/k031002.htm